# Fragment with Viewpager not refresh when close and open the app again

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

I have `viewpager` with 3 fragment in it. In each fragment I do firebase query to populate `recycleview`. I using `addsinglevaluelistener` to query firebase real time database.The problem are:

1. When I updating my data then close the app and open it again, it
   does'nt updating the `recyclerview`. I have to close it and open again 1 
   more time to updating the data.
2. It also happen in my `swipe refresh` in each fragment, I have to
   `swipe refresh` 2 times to updating the data.

I tried to do:

1. Create my query in `onResume` , `Onstart`
2. Override `onPageSelected`

This also doesnt work for me

**Main Activity**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

//Tab Layout
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user == null) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };}



    private void setupTabIcons() {


        TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabOne.setText("Matakuliah");
        tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.mipmap.baseline_home_white_24dp, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);


        tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabTwo.setText("Tugas");
        tabTwo.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.mipmap.baseline_assignment_late_white_24dp, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);

        tabThree = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabThree.setText("Pengumuman");
        tabThree.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_notifications_black_24dp, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(tabThree);
        BadgeView badge3 = new BadgeView(getApplicationContext(), tabThree);



    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFrag(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 2 : ((ThreeFragment)adapter.getItem(position)).LoadDataPengumuman();
            case 1 : ((TwoFragment)adapter.getItem(position)).LoadData();
                viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }


    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }



        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**ThreeFragment**

```
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user_course");
        users = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mataKuliahRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("courses");
        daftarPengumumanRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("pengumuman");
        pengumumanRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("pengumuman_course");
        mFlagPengumuman = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("flag_pengumuman");

        LoadDataPengumuman();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user_course");
        users = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mataKuliahRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("courses");
        daftarPengumumanRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("pengumuman");
        pengumumanRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("pengumuman_course");
        mFlagPengumuman = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("flag_pengumuman");

        LoadDataPengumuman();


    }




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three, container, false);

        userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user_course");
        users = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mataKuliahRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("courses");
        daftarPengumumanRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("pengumuman");
        pengumumanRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("pengumuman_course");
        mFlagPengumuman = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("flag_pengumuman");

        swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);

        View b= ((MainActivity)getActivity()).tabThree;
        badge3 = new BadgeView(getActivity(), b);
        badge3.setBadgeMargin(90,0);
        badge3.setTextSize(10);


        counter = new Counter() {
            @Override
            public void setCounter(int count) {
                Log.e("Ser_Counter", "total countnya " + asd);
                Log.e("Ser_Counter", "masuk count ");
                asd=asd+count;
                if(asd==0){
                    Log.e("Ser_Counter", "masuk asd=0");
                    badge3.hide();

                }else{
                    Log.e("Ser_Counter", "masuk asd=else");

                    badge3.setText(asd + "");
                    badge3.show();
                }

            }
        };

        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override public void run() {
                        swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        listPengumuman.clear();
                        consolidatedList.clear();
                        LoadDataPengumuman();

                    }
                    private void onLoaded() {
                        swipeLayout.setEnabled(true);
                        swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }

                }, 500);
            }
        });



        mJumlahPengumuman = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.jumlah_pengumuman);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.PengumumanRView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        adapter = new myAdapterPengumuman(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), consolidatedList,counter);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        RecyclerViewHeader header = (RecyclerViewHeader) v.findViewById(R.id.header3);
        header.attachTo(mRecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        LoadDataPengumuman();

        return v;
    }
```

Comment: You can replace your FragmentPagerAdapter by FragmentStatePager Adapter and why you use viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3) ? This proper saved your screen. I think it will work if you remove it.

Comment: It still doenst work for me sir

Comment: Is it your viewpager state change listener works ?

Comment: I have solution but its still have problem, I add LoadDataPengumuman() to OnCreate, and it work. But 1 problem again, when i destroy my app then update the firebase. Its not updating the data, i need swipe refresh or reload app 1 more time. *note: after i destroy the app, this solution doesnt work again, so i have to compile a new solution again and again